# Single VD, Multiple Hosts,Multiple WCF Services

Tags: c#, wcf, soa, autofac

I have three different services in one VS solution.

IServiceA, IServiceB and IServiceC. All three services are independent in terms of functionality exposed and usage pattern(e.g. highly invoked versus rarely invoked, critical, non-critical). So each has its own implementation. But few things like `Logging`, `DataAccess` are shared.

I am going to create only single VD in IIS and put everything in it. We use WebFarm and services are stateless(PerCall)

**Question 1:** What benefit I will get if I use different host per contract instead one service implementing three contracts considering diverse usage pattern? Can unhandled exception in one Host still bring down other hosts?

**Question 2:** If having multiple hosts is advisable in this case, then how do I configure ServiceHostFactory and Autofac? Should I create only one ServiceHostFactory to create Hosts? I need an example here to configure DI in case of multiple WCF Hosts.

My Web.Config -

```
 <serviceHostingEnvironment>
      <serviceActivations>
        <add factory="CommonService.Host.ServiceAHostFactory,Host" service="CommonService.Contract.IServiceA,Contract" relativeAddress="ServiceA.svc"/>
        <add factory="CommonService.Host.ServiceBHostFactory,Host" service="CommonService.Contract.IServiceB,Contract" relativeAddress="ServiceB.svc"/>
        <add factory="CommonService.Host.ServiceCHostFactory,Host" service="CommonService.Contract.IServiceC,Contract" relativeAddress="ServiceC.svc"/>
      </serviceActivations>
  </serviceHostingEnvironment>

public class ServiceAHostFactory:AutofacHostFactory
    {
        public override ServiceHostBase CreateServiceHost(string constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses)
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.RegisterType<ServiceA>().As<IServiceA>();
            Container = builder.Build();
            return base.CreateServiceHost(constructorString, baseAddresses);

        }

        protected override ServiceHost CreateSingletonServiceHost(object singletonInstance, Uri[] baseAddresses)
        {
            return new ServiceHost(singletonInstance, baseAddresses);
        }
    }

 public class ServiceBHostFactory:AutofacHostFactory
    {
        public override ServiceHostBase CreateServiceHost(string constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses)
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.RegisterType<ServiceB>().As<IServiceB>();
            Container = builder.Build();
            return base.CreateServiceHost(constructorString, baseAddresses);

        }

        protected override ServiceHost CreateSingletonServiceHost(object singletonInstance, Uri[] baseAddresses)
        {
            return new ServiceHost(singletonInstance, baseAddresses);
        }
    }
```

and one more host factory for ServiceC. 
I would like to improve this design, so comments are welcome. Right now I have only three services, but going forward we are going to add few more.

Is this how it is done? Or am i missing something? or completely on wrong path?

Comment: I don't have experience with DI, so I can't completely answer your question. However, each service will run in it's own `ServiceHost` - it's a 1:1 relationship.  A given instance of `ServiceHost` can only host *one* service, not multiple services.  An unhandled exception in one host should not bring down other hosts, as I would expect them to be running in separate app domains.  However, if the unhandled exception brings down the application pool, that will bring down all the hosts.

Comment: I checked the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName for each service host and service instance and found that all three service hosts along with service instances were residing in same AppDomain